# identificando provedor de email na lista

Tags: python, sistema-de-arquivos

acredito que não exista pergunta irrelevante então lá vai:

Estou começando a estudar python para data analytics e me deparei com um desafio de ler um .csv com alguns emails e separa os provedores deste arquivo em variaveis. A lógica eu até consigo compreender, mas por falta de conhecimento, estou apanhando para a sintaxe da linguagem.

Segue a minha tentativa muito falha: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u2sGyeOw9rZlxStlslE3euot8j1zn_i3?usp=sharing

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3):

Utilize a função [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) do python para manusear uma string.